# ERROR 1506: Foreign keys are not yet supported in conjunction with partitioning SQL Statement

Tags: mysql

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `databasename`.`tablename` 
 PARTITION BY HASH(id) PARTITIONS 4 ;

ERROR 1506: Foreign keys are not yet supported in conjunction with partitioning
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `databasename`.`tablename` 
 PARTITION BY HASH(id) PARTITIONS 4

Comment: 'InnoDB storage engine.  InnoDB foreign keys and MySQL partitioning are not compatible. Partitioned InnoDB tables cannot have foreign key references, nor can they have columns referenced by foreign keys. ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-partitioning-excerpt/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-storage-engines.html. -

Comment: So how to use PARTITIONING when we have foreign key references

Comment: Ermm You don't BTW what version of mysql are you on.

Comment: I am using  MySQL 8.0.15 version

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys are not supported by Innodb:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-partitioning-excerpt/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations.html

However, if you really need to enforce data integrity on the DB level, you can use triggers as a workaround, please see:

http://opendba.blogspot.com/2008/10/mysql-partitioned-tables-with-trigger.html

This approach is not recommended because it may cost in performance and will be hard to maintain:

https://www.techmixing.com/2018/11/advantages-disadvantages-of-sql-trigger.html